# SSL .pk12 importing error using ikeyman

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, ibm-jdk

I have generated CSR and downloaded .pk12 file from the CA. While I'm trying to import this getting error as

An IO Exception has occurred:
DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=47, too big.

Error details are as ::

Error Code:
58
Stack Trace:
com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.error.KeyManagerException: java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=47, too big.
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.keystore.KeyStoreProxyCreatorFactory$FileKeyStoreProxy.load(KeyStoreProxyCreatorFactory.java:264)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.keystore.KeyStoreProxyCreatorFactory$AbstractKeyStoreProxy.getKeyStore(KeyStoreProxyCreatorFactory.java:187)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.keystore.KeyStoreItemFactory.getPKCS12KeyStoreItem(KeyStoreItemFactory.java:338)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.keystore.KeyStoreItemFactory.newPKCS12KeyStoreItem(KeyStoreItemFactory.java:332)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.keystore.KeyStoreItemFactory.loadKeystore(KeyStoreItemFactory.java:141)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.command.KeyStoreLoaderFactory$BasicKeyStoreLoader.getKeyStoreItem(KeyStoreLoaderFactory.java:48)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.command.KeyStoreLoaderFactory$CachedKeyStoreLoader.getKeyStoreItem(KeyStoreLoaderFactory.java:83)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.command.KeyStoreLoaderFactory$BasicKeyStoreLoader.getValidKeyStoreItem(KeyStoreLoaderFactory.java:53)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.command.Command.getValidKeystoreItem(Command.java:104)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.command.CommandFactory$LoadDbCommand.run(CommandFactory.java:531)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.command.Command.invoke(Command.java:198)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.command.gui.KeymanController$Invoker.invoke(KeymanController.java:261)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.command.gui.RetrieverFactory$ImportRetriever.getImportParameters(RetrieverFactory.java:509)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.command.gui.RetrieverFactory$ExportRetriever.getParameters(RetrieverFactory.java:556)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.command.gui.RetrieverFactory$CompoundRetriever.getParameters(RetrieverFactory.java:149)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.command.gui.KeymanController.getParameters(KeymanController.java:139)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.command.gui.KeymanController.getParameters(KeymanController.java:130)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.command.gui.KeymanController.actionPerformed(KeymanController.java:91)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.gui.panels.KeymanPanel.fireActionPerformed(KeymanPanel.java:54)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.gui.panels.KeymanPanel.actionPerformed(KeymanPanel.java:48)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.gui.panels.KeymanPanel.fireActionPerformed(KeymanPanel.java:54)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.gui.panels.KeymanPanel.actionPerformed(KeymanPanel.java:48)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.gui.panels.ContentsPanel.actionPerformed(ContentsPanel.java:334)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.gui.panels.KeymanPanel.fireActionPerformed(KeymanPanel.java:54)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.gui.panels.KeymanPanel.actionPerformed(KeymanPanel.java:48)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2006)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2329)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:398)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:253)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:247)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:283)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6052)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3276)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5817)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2069)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4424)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4254)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4333)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3997)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3927)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2113)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2451)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4254)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:610)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:284)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:194)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:179)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:171)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:132)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=47, too big.
    at com.ibm.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:724)
    at com.ibm.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:698)
    at com.ibm.security.util.DerValue.(DerValue.java:253)
    at com.ibm.security.util.DerInputStream.getDerValue(DerInputStream.java:499)
    at com.ibm.security.pkcsutil.PKCSDerObject.decode(PKCSDerObject.java:258)
    at com.ibm.security.pkcs12.PFX.(PFX.java:134)
    at com.ibm.crypto.provider.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.keystore.KeyStoreProxyCreatorFactory$FileKeyStoreProxy.performLoad(KeyStoreProxyCreatorFactory.java:296)
    at com.ibm.gsk.ikeyman.keystore.KeyStoreProxyCreatorFactory$FileKeyStoreProxy.load(KeyStoreProxyCreatorFactory.java:245)
    ... 50 more

What is causing the error ?

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) Check if there are additional characters (including blank lines) after the 'END CERTIFICATE' line in your file. 2) Ensure that the target key store is of type PKCS12.

Comment: 1) No blanks 2) Targetted to every key store. Getting same error.

Comment: Need further clarification: 1) The file ext for the PKCS12 format is .p12 or .pfx. Is that a typo? 2) As you're importing the certificate to a WebSphere key store, what happens when you try this with the Admin Console?

Comment: file type is .pk12 , and can you please explain how to it throughth the Admin Console ?